# Apache POI alternative for Windows 7 excel

Tags: java, apache, excel, apache-poi

Our application uses POI API (poi-2.5.1.jar) for reading from excel files and to create excel files.

In future the application also needs to support Windows 7.

But I think POI API does not support Windows 7 excel.

1) What is the alternative ?

2) Is there a solution available which is backward compatible as well ?

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are confused. There is no "Windows 7 Excel", there are just different versions of Excel. Most notably, there is the pre-2003 office file format (`.xls` or HSSF in POI diction) and the new XML-based format (`.xlsx` or XSSF in POI diction).

POI supports both and the distinction is fairly transparent from a user model point of view, though you'll probably need to [adapt old XLS-only code](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/converting.html).

Comment: The OP will also need to upgrade - POI 2.5 is about 7 years old! For XSSF (which provides .xlsx support) you need at least POI 3.5, but the latest code (currently 3.8 beta 4) is highly recommended